# How to fetch data from supabase in flutter?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, supabase

This is now my database in supabase. I'm trying to fetch all the rows with post id 1.
So I want to get potato, carrot, meat, water.

| ingredient_id(pk) | post_id(fk) | order | ingredient |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | potato |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | carrot |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | meat |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | water |

But I don't know if I should use stream or select or something. When I use .select('ingredient').eq('post', 1), I don't know what to use next, not single.

```
fetchData() {
  final stream = Supabase.instance.client
  .from('post_ingredient')
  .stream(primaryKey: ['ingredient_id'])
  .order('order', ascending: true);

  return StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
      final table = snapshot.data!;

      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: table.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(table[index]['ingredient'].toString());
        },
      );
    }
  );
 }
```

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: _appBar(),
    body: fetchData(),
  );
}
```

Please give me a solution or tips, idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it in three days.

```
final stream = Supabase.instance.client
  .from('post_ingredient')
  .stream(primaryKey: ['ingredient_id'])
  .inFilter('post_id', [1]) // add this
  .order('order', ascending: true);
```

Too few sorce codes use flutter and superbase at the same time ㅠㅠ